# How to access Aggregate Field Value as Currency?

Tags: delphi, aggregate, currency, tclientdataset

When I try to access the value of an **aggregate field** (SUM_TOTAL) as the following line:

```
DM.cdsTOTAL.AsCurrency := DM.cdsItemSUM_TOTAL.AsCurrency;
```

The following error occurs:

**Cannot access field 'SUM_TOTAL' as type float.**

My temporary solution is this:

```
DM.cdsTOTAL.AsCurrency := StrToCurrDef(DM.cdsItemSUM_TOTAL.AsString, 0);
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: How is your SQL statement defined? You probably need to add a typecast.

Comment: What is the exact type of your DM.cdsItemSUM_TOTAL Field?

Comment: The type of `DM.cdsItemSUM_TOTAL` is **TAggregateField**

Comment: Make sure the conversion to decimal or real is not required here.

Comment: My temporary solution is this: `DM.cdsTOTAL.AsCurrency := StrToCurrDef(DM.cdsItemSUM_TOTAL.AsString, 0);` Any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to show us how SUM_TOTAL is generated. Not what it's named, not that it's TAggregateField, but how the value is generated for the field **content**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Class Helpers for  TAggregateField and if needed for TAggregate

```
type
  TAggregateHelper=Class Helper for TAggregate
  private
    function GetCurrency: Currency;
  published
    Property asCurrency:Currency read GetCurrency;
  End;

  TAggregateFieldHelper=Class Helper for TAggregateField
  private
    function GetCurrency: Currency;
  published
    Property asCurrency:Currency read GetCurrency;
  End;


implementation



{ TAggregateHelper }

function TAggregateHelper.GetCurrency: Currency;
begin
  if not VarIsNull(Value) then
     Result := Value
  else Result := Value;
end;
{ TAggregateFieldHelper }

function TAggregateFieldHelper.GetCurrency: Currency;
begin
  if not VarIsNull(Value) then
     Result := Value
  else Result := Value;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage(FloatToStr(CDSTotal.AsCurrency) + '-' + FloatToStr(CDS.Aggregat[0].asCurrency));
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

that's how TAggregateField is underdesigned. see implementation details in db.pas to get the idea that it doesn't override base TField.GetAs... family that provokes aforementioned AccessError

Comment: My temporary solution is this: `DM.cdsTOTAL.AsCurrency := StrToCurrDef(DM.cdsItemSUM_TOTAL.AsString, 0);` Any other suggestions?

Comment: converting internal variant value to string form just to immediately convert that string to currency isn't the best idea

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark:

```
begin
  If DM.cdsItemSUM_TOTAL.IsNull then
  begin 
    DM.cdsTOTAL.AsCurrency := 0;
  end 
  else
  begin
     DM.cdsTOTAL.AsCurrency := Currency(DM.cdsItemSUM_TOTAL.Value);
  end;
end;
```

Since the value is a float (probably a double), I believe it can cast to a currency variable.

Comment: problem with null values: Exception class EVariantTypeCastError with message 'Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (Currency)

Comment: I assumed that exist an numeric value to cast. Edited

Comment: [portuguese]Não aposte que nenhum moderador aqui sabe português. O que você pediu pode criar problemas pra vc aqui.[/portuguese] But the question is interesting. +1 on it.